# Высота status bar'a

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким можно получить высоту `status bar`?
Мне нужно знать высоту экрана без `Toolbar` и `status bar`.
Общая высота экрана у меня определяется так:

```
private void getScreenSize(){
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
}
```

Высота `Toolbar` так:

```
private void getHeightToolbar(){
    toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            toolbarHeight = toolbar.getHeight();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Высота статусбара

```
public static int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
    //always 24dp
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");

    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Высота тулбара

(заданная через атрибут `android:height="?actionBarSize"`)

> Надо только иметь в виду, что не всякий контекст подойдёт. ApplicationContext, например, будет 0 возвращать – [ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) [27 мар в 19:30](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644760/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-status-bara/644764?noredirect=1#comment918220_644764)

```
public static int getActionBarSize(Context context) {
    //always 56dp
    int result = 0;
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)){
        result = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Надо только иметь в виду, что не всякий контекст подойдёт. ApplicationContext, например, будет 0 возврашать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, спасибо, дополнил ответ

Comment: Подскажите, я правильно понимаю, что возвращается высота в dp?

Comment: @Александр нет, возвращает в пикселях, коммент я для себя написал, дабы не забыть (мало ли где в разметке это надо будет учесть)